# Как сделать кнопку для скачивания 2 файлов одновременно?

Tags: html

```
<a href="1.jpg" download>Скачать файл</a>
```

такой вариант скачивает 1 файл, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Скачать файл" скачалось 2 файла?

Comment: Нигде такого не видел, может быть в архив два файла поместить?

Comment: @oneLEAM, такое есть однозначно, думал может есть способ обойтись html, видимо придется что то с js думать, спасибо за совет)

Comment: В HTML нет, а с JS очень даже, хоть 100, только по очереди, главное что бы сервер выдавал ответ.